# Separate columns of a DataFrame by days of the week

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

Let it be the following Python Panda Dataframe (the original could include dates for several months):

| Hours | 2022-06-06 | 2022-06-07 | 2022-06-08 | 2022-06-09 | 2022-06-10 | 2022-06-11 | 2022-06-12 | 2022-06-13 | 2022-06-14 | 2022-06-15 | 2022-06-16 | 2022-06-17 | 2022-06-18 | 2022-06-19 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00:00 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 23 | 43 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 7 | 3 | 1 | 0 |
| 05:00 | 5 | 4 | 0 | 3 | 32 | 31 | 3 | 9 | 3 | 3 | 5 | 3 | 0 | 3 |
| 10:00 | 0 | 3 | 3 | 34 | 45 | 63 | 43 | 6 | 3 | 0 | 3 | 3 | 0 | 1 |
| 15:00 | 10 | 31 | 10 | 3 | 53 | 0 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 5 | 3 | 12 | 3 |
| 20:00 | 20 | 33 | 33 | 3 | 86 | 3 | 0 | 3 | 3 | 21 | 3 | 3 | 0 | 3 |
| 23:00 | 31 | 34 | 45 | 63 | 43 | 64 | 23 | 12 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 5 | 2 | 3 |

I want to create 2 dataframes by following the steps below:

1. Remove the columns corresponding to Saturdays and Sundays.

| Hours | 2022-06-06 | 2022-06-07 | 2022-06-08 | 2022-06-09 | 2022-06-10 | 2022-06-13 | 2022-06-14 | 2022-06-15 | 2022-06-16 | 2022-06-17 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00:00 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 23 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 7 | 3 |
| 05:00 | 5 | 4 | 0 | 3 | 32 | 9 | 3 | 3 | 5 | 3 |
| 10:00 | 0 | 3 | 3 | 34 | 45 | 6 | 3 | 0 | 3 | 3 |
| 15:00 | 10 | 31 | 10 | 3 | 53 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 5 | 3 |
| 20:00 | 20 | 33 | 33 | 3 | 86 | 3 | 3 | 21 | 3 | 3 |
| 23:00 | 31 | 34 | 45 | 63 | 43 | 12 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 5 |

2. Separate the resulting Dataframe into 2, one with only Fridays and the other with the rest of the days (Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday and Thursday).

| Hours | 2022-06-10 | 2022-06-17 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00:00 | 23 | 3 |
| 05:00 | 32 | 3 |
| 10:00 | 45 | 3 |
| 15:00 | 53 | 3 |
| 20:00 | 86 | 3 |
| 23:00 | 43 | 5 |

| Hours | 2022-06-06 | 2022-06-07 | 2022-06-08 | 2022-06-09 | 2022-06-13 | 2022-06-14 | 2022-06-15 | 2022-06-16 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00:00 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 7 |
| 05:00 | 5 | 4 | 0 | 3 | 9 | 3 | 3 | 5 |
| 10:00 | 0 | 3 | 3 | 34 | 6 | 3 | 0 | 3 |
| 15:00 | 10 | 31 | 10 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 5 |
| 20:00 | 20 | 33 | 33 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 21 | 3 |
| 23:00 | 31 | 34 | 45 | 63 | 12 | 1 | 0 | 2 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and [`weekday`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.weekday.html) to create a boolean indexer, then use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
# set index aside
df = df.set_index('Hours')

# get weekday (4 is Fri, 5 and 6 are Sat and Sun)

# compare to 5 (<5) to get True on weekdays
weekdays = pd.to_datetime(df.columns).weekday < 5
# or
# monthu = pd.to_datetime(df.columns).weekday < 4

# compare to 4 to get Fridays
fri = pd.to_datetime(df.columns).weekday == 4

# slice
mon_thu_df = df.loc[:, weekdays & ~fri].reset_index()
# or
# mon_thu_df = df.loc[:, monthu].reset_index()

fri_df = df.loc[:, fri].reset_index()
```

Mon-Thu:

```
   Hours  2022-06-06  2022-06-07  2022-06-08  2022-06-09  2022-06-13  2022-06-14  2022-06-15  2022-06-16
0  00:00           3           0           0           3           2           3           3           7
1  05:00           5           4           0           3           9           3           3           5
2  10:00           0           3           3          34           6           3           0           3
3  15:00          10          31          10           3           3           3           3           5
4  20:00          20          33          33           3           3           3          21           3
5  23:00          31          34          45          63          12           1           0           2
```

Fri:

```
   Hours  2022-06-10  2022-06-17
0  00:00          23           3
1  05:00          32           3
2  10:00          45           3
3  15:00          53           3
4  20:00          86           3
5  23:00          43           5
```

Answer (score 1):

For the first Step you can make something like this :

```
def allsundays(year):
        d = date(year, 1, 1)                    # January 1st
        d += timedelta(days = 6 - d.weekday())  # First Sunday
        while d.year == year:
            yield d
            d += timedelta(days = 7)
    
for d in allsundays(2022):
    print(d)
```

This little code can help you to get all Sunday

After getting the sunday list you can drop the columns :

```
df.drop(columns=sunday_list)
```